# Roots of a polynomial of $n^{\rm th}$ degree having phase $e^{\frac{i2\pi}{m}}$

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, roots

Having a polynomial $p_n(x)$ of degree $n$ with real coefficients and only complex solutions (i.e., no real solutions) $x_1,\dots,x_n$ and $0 < \arg(x_k) < 2\pi$ for all $k\in\{1,...,n\}$, is it generally possible that some solution $x_k$ fulfills $\arg\left(x_k^m\right)=0$ (in other words it be positively real) if $m<n$ ?

I presume it is not possible, but can it be proven?

Comment: Your question is unclear to me. If $p(x)$ has some positive real root $x_k$ then $x_k^m$ is positive real for any $m > 0$.

Comment: edited to make it clearer.

Comment: $p(x) = x^3+1$ is a counter-example. The solution $x=-1$ satisfies $x^2 = 1 > 0$.

Comment: Even more clear?^^

Comment: Now $p(x) = x^6+1$ is a counter-example. The solutions $x=\pm i$ satisfy $x^4 = 1 > 0$.

Comment: Generally you can choose $x_1$ as an $m$-th root of unity, and $x_2, \ldots, x_n$ arbitrary (non-real).

Comment: That is actually true :-/. 
Considering all the coefficients are real, can there be made such conclusions if the coefficients obey certain contraints?

Comment: $p(x) = x^6 +1$ has only real coefficients ...

Comment: Yes, but is it possible to see this from the coefficients alone, or can this only be checked in each case specifically? For example in the discriminant, there will be a factor of $\sin^2\left(\frac{2\pi}{m}\right)$ appearing, or?

Answer (score 0):

It seems trivial to me, or I missed something.

Take any phase $\theta$ you want, pick a real number $r$, then

$p(x) = [\text{some other factors}](x^2+1)^2\cdot(x-re^{i\theta})(x-re^{-i\theta})$ would be a solution.

Comment: Yes, but I'm trying to construct cases in which it is true. For instance as mentioned above in the discriminant, there will be a factor of $-4r^2\sin^2\left(\frac{2\pi}{m}\right)$, so if that expression is irrational for a given $m$, while the discriminant is an integer, can this factor be canceled by some other contribution in the discriminant of another root?

Comment: Can you clarify? If there is a (pair of) repeated root, the discriminant would be zero automatically, which is an integer... @Diger

Comment: The roots are all distinct.